# Publish Flutter to google play 64 bit issue

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to close test a flutter app but I keep getting the error ----

"This release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement

The following APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code: 21.

Include 64-bit and 32-bit native code in your app. Use the Android App Bundle publishing format to automatically ensure that each device architecture receives only the native code it needs. This avoids increasing the overall size of your app. Learn More"

I tried building it in 64 and 32 bit apk's and uploading them per this article - https://medium.com/@truongsinh/flutter-android-64-bit-so-what-the-fuss-15da6f8e3a46

but its still throwing the error. Whats the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [codemagic](https://codemagic.io) and forgot all the things about upload your app to Google Play or AppStore manually

Comment: Believe me, use codemagic and you'll see the changes immediately, also you can forget all the things about generate apps and upload app to the stores

Comment: What all does it handle for u? Does it do the signing and the app bundle? Everything on my end was working until I went to release it to my test group and that’s when I got the 64 bit error which apparently is a show stopper

Comment: We are using Azure dev ops, I cant get Codemagic authenticated to add my app